# How do you write a Visual Studio plugin to manipulate your own file type?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, plugins

When you are developing a Windows form, you get the form designer and when you double click a button on that designer, it generates a method stub and you get to edit that method.

When you are editing an XSD, you can do so from the designer or the code.

If you have the Enterprise Libraries installed, you can right click an app.config and click "Edit Enterprise Library Configuration" which brings up a Window within a document tab that edits the XML under the hood of the app.config (although the UI on this is a little more clunky than the above two examples for one reason or another).

I wish to create one of these plugins, how do I do it?

Should it make a difference, the UI I wish to get to is as follows:

There will be rows, with a combo box for one column.
I can select an item from the combo box and click a button on that row, this will create a method stub with an attribute that contains data from the combo box.

I intend this to work in reverse too: when you load a class into this plugin, it will list in the rows the methods with the relevant attribute.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Start off at the [Visual Studio Extensibility Developer Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsx/default.aspx), download the SDK, and have fun!

Comment: Worth noting that the SDK download on that page is for vanilla VS2010.  If you've got SP1 you'll need the [SDK for VS2010 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=21307c23-f0ff-4ef2-a0a4-dca54ddb1e21)